# Annotated value gives None, need 0

Tags: python, django

```
order_list_cases =(order_list.values('user_id').annotate(dcount=Count('user_id'),customer_paid_sum=(Sum('invoice__transaction_invoice__transaction_amount'))
```

In this code, the `customer_paid_sum`is returning None, I want to give it as 0 if it is None. I tried else case along with it but didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) to return `0` instead of `None` if the aggregate works over an empty collection:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

order_list_cases = order_list.values('user_id').annotate(
    dcount=Count('user_id'),
    customer_paid_sum=Coalesce(
        Sum('invoice__transaction_invoice__transaction_amount'),
        Value(0)
    )
)
```